# How to call a function at regular intervals without blocking the execution of other different threads?

Tags: multithreading, rust, rust-tokio

The idea is to have a function that is executed every 10 seconds but in the meantime other threads have to do their work.

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::{task, time};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    for i in 0..3 {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            //thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(3));
            println!("I'am the thread {}", i);
        });
    }

    let forever = task::spawn(async {
        let mut interval = time::interval(Duration::from_secs(10));
        loop {
            interval.tick().await;
            println!("Waited 10 seconds!");
        }
    });

    forever.await.unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Please post all of your code. This snippet by itself looks fine.

Comment: Ok, the problem here is that all thread code is executed before. If i use sleep it alternates, but I don't think using thread::sleep is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try to not use `thread::spawn` in an async context as your runtime already has a thread pool for you and try to not use blocking operations like `thread::sleep`.

You'll find all different `spawn_..` flavors in the [tokio crate](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/index.html#functions) that allows you to do heavy computation (kinda thread blocking) or just polling async.

Here is an example how you can do things concurrently with sleep and interval.

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::{
    select,
    task::spawn,
    time::{interval, sleep},
};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let tick_1s = spawn(ticker(1));
    let tick_3s = spawn(ticker(3));

    let timeout = sleep(Duration::from_secs(10));
    select! {
        _ = tick_1s => {}
        _ = tick_3s => {}
        _ = timeout => {}
    };
}

async fn ticker(secs: u64) {
    let mut interval = interval(Duration::from_secs(secs));
    interval.tick().await; // skip first tick

    loop {
        interval.tick().await;
        println!("Waited {}s!", secs);
    }
}

// Waited 1s!
// Waited 1s!
// Waited 1s!
// Waited 3s!
// Waited 1s!
// Waited 1s!
// Waited 1s!
// Waited 3s!
// Waited 1s!
// Waited 1s!
// Waited 1s!
// Waited 3s!
// Waited 1s!
```

Comment: Does the thread pool get created for any tokio app or only when the compiler detects `tokio::task::spawn_blocking` is present in the source?

Comment: Latter is not possible. The tokio runtime is actually set up by the code itself: https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/index.html. `#[tokio::main]` is the default for [a multi-threaded rt](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/attr.main.html#using-the-multi-thread-runtime) which is one thread per CPU core as default.

Comment: Just to clarify I was referring to the [blocking threads](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/index.html#cpu-bound-tasks-and-blocking-code) Tokio uses, distinct from the core threads which are for running async code on. I've found an answer which is they are spawned ad hoc, and can be kept alive for a configurable amount of time when used.